# How to get last created document in couchdb?

Tags: couchdb

How can I get last created document in couchdb? Maybe some how I can use _changes feature of couchdb? But [documentation says](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_database_API#Changes), that I only can get list of document, ordered by first created document, ant there is no way to change order.

So how can I get last created document?

Answer (score 17):

You can get the changes feed in descending order as it's also a view.

```
GET /dbname/_changes?descending=true
```

You can use limit= as well, so;

```
GET /dbname/_changes?descending=true&limit=1
```

will give the latest update.

Answer (score 5):

Your only surefire way to get the last created document is to include a timestamp (`created_at` or something) with your document. From there, you just need a simple view to output all the docs by their creation date.

I was going to suggest using the `last_seq` information from the database, but the sequence number changes with **every** single write, and replication also complicates the matter further.